# Sparql - Count of multiple categories of connected nodes

Tags: sparql

In my graph, a node of category 'File' 'Owns' many nodes of varying categories.  I'm trying to get a list of Files, including a count of connected nodes of specific categories.

My current best query looks like this:

```
SELECT ?uuid ?fileName ?tableCount ?toCount
WHERE {
    ?uuid 'Category' 'File' .
    ?uuid 'Name' ?fileName .
    {
        SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?tableCount)
        WHERE
        {
            VALUES (?category ) { ('BaseTable') }
            ?uuid 'Owns' ?elemUUID .
            ?elemUUID 'Category' ?category .
        }   
    }
    {
        SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?toCount)
        WHERE
        {
            VALUES (?category ) { ('TableOccurrence') }
            ?uuid 'Owns' ?elemUUID .
            ?elemUUID 'Category' ?category .
        }   
    }
}
```

The output is a distinct list of files, but the counts are the count for that category across ALL files (i.e. every file shares the same value for ?toCount, and every file shares the same value for ?tableCount).

There's obviously something I'm not understanding about the way subqueries work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SPARQL evaluation is bottom up, i.e. subqueries first - thus, they are not aware of the bindings of the outer query.

Comment: Okay, @UninformedUser... But then how would one accomplish this kind of accumulation the RIGHT way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in inner queries are not scoped outside, unless they appear in the selection.
What you should do is a query like this instead (forgive my editing, but this will make it much easier to follow for other users too):

```
SELECT ?uuid ?fileName ?tableCount ?toCount
WHERE {
    ?uuid :category 'File' .
    ?uuid :name ?fileName .
    {
        SELECT ?uuid (COUNT(*) as ?tableCount)
        WHERE
        {
            VALUES (?category ) { ('BaseTable') }
            ?uuid :owns ?elemUUID .
            ?elemUUID :category ?category .
        }
        GROUP BY ?uuid   #This is the missing link
    }
    {
        SELECT ?uuid (COUNT(*) as ?toCount)
        WHERE
        {
            VALUES (?category ) { ('TableOccurrence') }
            ?uuid :owns ?elemUUID .
            ?elemUUID :category ?category .
        } 
        GROUP BY ?uuid  #and here again
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, and completely understandable.  I'm not 100% thrilled by the performance, though.  Is there a better way to accomplish this goal, or is this "the way"?

Comment: I believe there is no other way to do what you want.
If you have write permissions, you can always insert triples like this:
`INSERT {?a :hasTOCount ?ct} WHERE {SELECT ?a (COUNT(*) AS ?ct) WHERE {...} GROUP BY ?a}`
Then you can query this directly.
This can of course become out of date if the data changes.
Some triplestore let you materialise 'rules' which achieve the same thing as the above, but should help keep a consistent system.

Comment: Great.  Thank you, @Valerio.